# How do I paginate json data in php

Tags: php, json, pagination

I have json data that looks like this

```
{
"project_no":1693,
"project_name":"Theresa Project",
"description":"Nonumy euismod ornatus usu te, quodsi viderer accommodare sea cu, ut alterum officiis nec. At deleniti eloquentiam vis. Explicari definitionem ei sea. No nec erat fugit voluptaria, in his elit discere fastidii. Aperiri virtute no eos. Te per habemus vulputate, partem iuvaret intellegebat eam in.",
"project_cost":10000.00,
}
{
"project_no":1664,
"project_name":"School Supplies for Children",
"description":"Nonumy euismod ornatus usu te, quodsi viderer accommodare sea cu, ut alterum officiis nec. At deleniti eloquentiam vis. Explicari definitionem ei sea. No nec erat fugit voluptaria, in his elit discere fastidii. Aperiri virtute no eos. Te per habemus vulputate, partem iuvaret intellegebat eam in. ",
"project_cost":8000.00,
},
```

I have over 60 records, With php I want to show 10 records on each page and dynamically populate the page numbers based on how many records I have.

Heres how I'm displaying the data.

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://linktojsondata.com');
$obj = json_decode($json, true);

<?php
$i = 0;
foreach ($obj as $project_name => $project_info) { ?>
    <a href="single-project-detail.php/<?php echo $project_info['project_no'];?>">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" alt="" src="<?php echo $project_info['featured_image_url']; ?>">
    </a>  
    <a href="single-project-detail.php/<?php echo $project_info['project_no'];?>">
        <?php echo $project_info['project_name']; ?>
    </a>
    <p>
        <?php $string = strip_tags($project_info['description']);?>
    </p>  
<?php if (++$i == 10) break; } ?>
```

Comment: I recommended using JavaScript since you need to fetch data async anyway. Then it is easier to handle the data later on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start, you will split the json array into blocks of `10` using `array_chunk`, and then loop through this using the page number `$_GET['p'] - 1` so your page url may look like `page.php?p=2` which will select the second set of data.

```
$pages = array_chunk(json_decode($json, true), 10, true);

foreach ($pages[$_GET['p'] - 1] as $project_name => $project_info) {

// your code

}
```